# Understanding Iptables rules to prevent DDoS

Tags: rhel, iptables, ip, firewall

Following `IPTables` rules exist on my system as some preventive measures against DDoS attacks

```
-A INPUT -s 255.0.0.0/8 -j LOG --log-prefix "Spoofed source IP" 
-A INPUT -s 255.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 0.0.0.0/8 -j LOG --log-prefix "Spoofed source IP"
-A INPUT -s 0.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
```

Is it restricting private `IP Address Group` with the assumption that packets originating from private IP Address range from Internet are actually spoofed IP Address. 
Also, How to calculate the corresponding IP Address range from the above subnets ?

Comment: Note that `iptables` rules only causes the packets to be dropped/rejected AFTER they have already been received by your router/network-interface.  They still consume bandwidth on your network interface.   This can be enough to prevent your network services (e.g. apache) from being overloaded with too much bogus work, but if you are under serious DDoS attack, you need to talk to your service provider to have the packets blocked upstream from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-A INPUT -s` adds a rule for any packets with the *source* subnets specified on the line.

Therefore, in your example, you are logging and dropping all packets that have a source IP address that starts with `255` and all that start with `0`, such as `255.1.2.3.4` or `0.56.78.90`

The idea here is that there should will never be packets that start with those addresses and therefore if they do appear, they must be spoofed.

There are actually many more invalid or reserved IP addresses that the ones you've listed which could be added to that list.

There are plenty of resources on [subnets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_subnetting_reference) and plenty of online subnet calculators to help you out.  In your case, the `/8` states that the first 8 bits of the IP address specify the network and all the others (the remaining 24) specify a host within that subnet.  In both examples, the first octet (8 bits) is the network and the other three octets can be any value. Your `255.0.0.0/8` therefore can be from `255.0.0.0` to `255.255.255.255` and your `0.0.0.0/8` can be from `0.0.0.0` to `0.255.255.255`.